# How will i extract the data from the docx file using DocumentFormat.OpenXml -details below

Tags: c#, xml, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I have a Docx file created by adding the xml schema. I am giving you the link of the docx file .[image]

now I want to extract-- To,From,heading,body.
Currently I am using the Library DocumentFormat.OpemXml.
But didnt succeed.
Can any one suggest me the steps .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to explore the DocumentFormat.OpenXml for the extraction of your data from the docx file.
Or Another method is that,

First convert the extension of the docx file to .zip .
After opening the zip file open the file document.xml.
In this file you will find all your data .
Now you just need to do is to read the xml file in c# and extract the data.
You use xmlDocument class and extract The data

I think it will be useful.

Comment: ye thanks atleast someone replied ,Now I will start working on you method.