# Update a database from a .docx file

Tags: sql, xml, docx

I have a HR web application which includes organization structure within workplaces.
The client is sending a .docx file with workplace name and its description. I need to make a C# application to get data from the .docx file and update some database tables with it.

I already tried .docx conversion to XML but I have no idea how to pick up data from that XML and insert it into the database.

Is there a easier way to update this database directly from a .docx file or what mechanics should I use to find data in the XML file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602737/how-will-i-extract-the-data-from-the-docx-file-using-documentformat-openxml-det is a good start

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

[image]

Below is the connection string to the database. You can modify it to suit yours

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=dbFiles; Integrated Security=true"/>
</connectionStrings >
```

To start with I have added a FileUpload control, a button and a Label to show messages

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""
Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>
```

And here is the snippet which is called on the Upload Button Click event

**C#**

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;  
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string contenttype = String.Empty;

    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
    switch(ext)
    {
        case ".doc":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".docx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".xls":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case ".jpg":
            contenttype = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case ".png":
            contenttype = "image/png";
            break;
        case ".gif":
            contenttype = "image/gif";
            break;
        case ".pdf":
            contenttype = "application/pdf";
            break;
    }
    if (contenttype != String.Empty)
    {

        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        //insert the file into database
        string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" +
           " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
          = contenttype;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
        InsertUpdateData(cmd);
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  
        lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;   
        lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." +
          " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";
    }
}
```

**VB.Net**

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  ' Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
  Dim filePath As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
  Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
  Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)
  Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty

  'Set the contenttype based on File Extension
  Select Case ext
    Case ".doc"
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"
      Exit Select
    Case ".docx"
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"
      Exit Select
    Case ".xls"
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
      Exit Select
    Case ".xlsx"
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
      Exit Select
    Case ".jpg"
      contenttype = "image/jpg"
      Exit Select
    Case ".png"
      contenttype = "image/png"
      Exit Select
    Case ".gif"
      contenttype = "image/gif"
      Exit Select
    Case ".pdf"
      contenttype = "application/pdf"
      Exit Select
    End Select
    If contenttype <> String.Empty Then
      Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
      Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
      Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)

      'insert the file into database
       Dim strQuery As String = "insert into tblFiles" _
       & "(Name, ContentType, Data)" _
       & " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"
       Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value _
       = contenttype
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
       InsertUpdateData(cmd)
       lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
       lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully"
     Else
       lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
       lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." _
       & " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats"
     End If
  End Sub
```

The above code simply reads the uploaded File as Stream and then converts the Stream to Byte array using Binary Reader and then the finally the byte arrays is saved to the database InsertUpdateData method executes the query to save the data in database

The InsertUpdateData function is given below

**C#**

```
private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: as much as I can appreciate the effort you put into providing a verbose answer for the OP, this doesn't answer his or her question: uploading the docx INTO the database in its entirety and extracting data FROM a docx and inserting THAT DATA into the db are two very different things.